# Trace memory allocations for individual requests on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, iis

I want to trace memory consumption per request in my ASP.NET MVC application that is hosted on IIS 10. I've already tried to work around it using ETW traces from PerfView but seems that I can't relate AspNetReq/Start and AspNetReq/Stop event with corresponding ObjectAllocated events because there could be another concurrent requests.

Is there a way to answer the next question "How many memory was consumed by the particular request" in ASP.NET and/or IIS? Any free/paid tools will be useful.

Update: Restatement of the question, after comments review:Is there a way to answer the next question "How much memory was allocated by the particular request?" in ASP.NET and/or IIS?

Comment: A request doesn't 'consume' memory, it only borrows it for a moment.

Comment: Consider also "shared" objects - e.g. connections in a connection pool, any caches, etc. One particular request may be the proximate cause of a particular object being created but multiple requests may be able to benefit from that object.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks, I do understand that there is GC and memory management. I restated the question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for your point. I've restated the question.

Comment: First you would need a profiler, as IIS itself does not provide you much insight. Second, profilers usually only provide process level analysis on how resources are used, and they won't be able to go deeper to thread level (requests are handled by worker threads). So it would be almost impossible to go to the level of details you like easily, unless you can make that request just between two memory snapshots, where the diff would be the info.